# Leaderboard : return 5 records, then the one I want, then 4 more records

Tags: mysql

I'm constructing a leaderboard, and I want a specific user to be in the middle of the returned records.

In other words, I want 5 higher scored users, then the user I want in the middle, then the next 4 lower:

```
   **users:**
    User, Score
    Rita, 9
    Sue, 8
    Bob, 7
    Bill, 6
    Sam, 5
    **ME, 4** <-- This would be the user I want in the middle.
    Sally, 3
    Simon, 2
    John, 1
    Jim, 0
```

I could do it in PHP, but just wanted to try and do it with a more elegant SQL statement.

I have literally no idea how I would even approach it!

Thanks

Comment: How do you identify the record you want? By the score, or by a user ID?

Comment: The middle user I want is ID'd by their user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Something to think about:

```
SELECT id,name FROM my_table;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Adam    |
|  2 | Ben     |
|  3 | Charlie |
|  4 | Adam    |
|  5 | Ben     |
|  6 | Dan     |
+----+---------+

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT id,name FROM my_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 2) x
UNION
(SELECT id,name FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2);
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Adam |
|  2 | Ben  |
|  6 | Dan  |
|  5 | Ben  |
+----+------+
```